# ASP.NET Views: Avoiding using <%@ Assembly... in every .aspx

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Virtually every .aspx page I have in my web site needs to have this at its top to function correctly:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
```

Is there anyway I can avoid having to declare this in the .aspx view for every page? Isn't there some way I can declare this globally for all .aspx views? Maybe something in the web.config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add it to [assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfyb45k1.aspx)

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</assemblies>
```

The @Assembly directive correspond to assemblies tag in web.config not namespace tag. Check [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d864zc1k.aspx)

Comment: It would be nice to know why it was down-voted so that whatever is incorrect can be corrected or improved :(

Answer (score 2):

You can declare it in web.config in the `assemblies` section, like this:

```
<system.web>
   <compilation>
      <assemblies>
         <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0 ... "/>        
      </assemblies>      
   </compilation>
</system.web>
```

However, according to the MSDN docs:

> Assemblies that reside in your Web application's \Bin directory are automatically linked to ASP.NET files within that application. Such assemblies do not require the @ Assembly directive. You can disable this functionality by removing the following line from the  section of your application's Web.config file:

```
<add assembly="*"/>
```

Comment: No, the @Assembly directive corresponds to the assembly config element

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can declare this in the web.config pages section.

Another alternative (if its available to you) is to use the new [Razor View engine](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx). It not only removes this type of code, but also provides cleaner, overall syntax. Of course, I realize this may not be a viable solution as you may be limited by your current technology/customer needs/etc.

An example of what you may see at the top of a Razor page is shown here:

```
@model Some.StronglyTyped.Model
@using Other.Libraries.To.Import
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Specific Page Title";
}
```

Comment: It's nice, but it won't solve the assembly issue. (The way to do the assembly reference in Razor is to add the reference to the project).

Answer (score -2):

Put it in the Web.config as a global namespace. It will be available to all your pages there.

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />  
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: No, the @Assembly directive corresponds to the assembly config element